# Proguard Retrace not working with stacktrace runtime info like  E/AndroidRuntime(10237):

Tags: android, proguard

I need to remove lines from my proguard.trace file like E/AndroidRuntime(10237):  in order for retrace to work.  Basically I am looking at log file and need to remove this lines or retrace does not work. Am I missing something or do I need to do this for every stacktrace? Basically its the information before that appears at the beginning of a stacktrace line like

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(10237):  at com.test.a.b.c(UnnownSource) :134
```

Here is the whole stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10237): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at ub.a(SourceFile:180)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at wp.getView(SourceFile:290)

E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      etc
E/        ( 2623): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

So I am running ./retrace.sh mapping.txt proguard.retrace the contents of which is above.  It will not retrace unless I remove  E/AndroidRuntime(10237): 
Am I missing some options to retrace. How do trace files need to be prepared for this to work?  I don't think its the mapping file because it works after I remove the first part of the line.

Comment: It should work anyway. How is it "not working" ?

Comment: It fails to unobfuscate the code until I remove the E/AndroidRuntime(10237).  Justs spits it back out.

Comment: Once I remove everything up to at it then works.

Comment: Proguard wasn't specifically designed for Android, so I suspect it can't handle any text in front of each line in a stacktrace.

Answer (score 49):

Proguard wants each "at" on a separate line, and only with white space before it. If it sees anything but white space before the at, it will not unobfuscate it.

Comment: This worked! O_o 
It would have taken me hours to figure this out myself. 
Thank you.

Comment: you can remove these lines using: sed -i '' -E "s/E\/AndroidRuntime[^at]+//g" your_trace_file

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of ReTrace can parse stack traces with the logcat prefixes like "E/AndroidRuntime(10237):", so it should no longer be a problem.

If you have a stack trace format that ReTrace can't parse, you can always specify your own regular expression with the option [-regex](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html).

Comment: Could you define recent? In what version of proguard was this fixed?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the ReTrace tool in ProGuard 4.8 and higher accepts these stack traces with logcat prefixes.

Comment: I have exactly Proguard 4.8 and I'm seeing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try [recat](https://github.com/EverythingMe/recat). It's a python script based on logcat-color, made exactly for this scenario, on-the-fly logcat deobfuscation (doesn't work on Windows though).
The main idea is that it deobfuscates each part of the log (tags/messages) separately.