# How to deobfuscate an Android stacktrace using mapping file

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I got a stacktrace from the crashreporting system and it is obfuscated, like

> ... Failed resolution of: Lru/test/c/b/a; ...

I have a mapping file.

How to deobfuscate this stacktrace using mapping.txt?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***Get deobfuscated crash stacktrace from your app page***

Upload your mapping.txt to your app PlayStore page with the following steps:

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Android vitals > Deobfuscation files.
4. Next to a version of your app, click Upload.
5. Upload the ProGuard mapping file for the version of your app.

After doing so, to view your deobfuscated crash stack traces:

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Android vitals > ANRs & Crashes.
4. Select a crash.
5. On the "Stack Traces" tab, you'll see your deobfuscated stack traces.

You can check [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en) for more details.

***Deobfuscate a piece of stacktrace***

To convert the code by yourself use the retrace script (retrace.bat on Windows; retrace.sh on Mac/Linux). It is located in the `~/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/` directory. The script takes the mapping.txt file and your stack trace, producing a new, readable stack trace. The syntax for using the retrace tool is:

```
retrace.bat|retrace.sh [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>]
```

Comment: The retrace script seems to be remove from the SDK or it is not in the path anymore. Your command is not working for me.

It can be found in: ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/retrace.sh

Comment: I've updated my answer @Janusz. Actually the `<sdk-root>` was already there but since i did not annotate it with '`' it was not showing, I only noticed it now. A bit late from my side but thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Ricard how can I find my proguard file path in windows

Comment: Error running 'retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt': Cannot run program "retrace.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\Swapit_Android\app"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Ricard I found where proguard installed I runned following command I am using windows and I am running following command retrace.bat [-verbose] mapping.txt but I am getting following error
Error: [-verbose] (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: you need to replace `[<stacktrace_file>]` with your obfuscated file, e.g: my_obfuscated_file.txt. The command should look like: retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_stack_trace.txt

Comment: I used retrace.sh [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>] worked and really helpful since app center doesn't retrace issues before uploaded mapping file.  thanks mate

Comment: Notice that the stack trace must start with "at": https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884485/6396770

Answer (score 16):

We can use pro-guard tool to retrace :

1st get the mapping file from the below location

```
<project-path>app/build/outputs/mapping/flavor/release/mapping.txt
```

> Find the pro-guard tool i.e. "proguardgui" from the below location

```
<your-computer-name>/AppData/Local/Android/SDK/tools/proguard/lib
```

then you will get `proguardgui.jar`

On mac : `/Users/<your computer name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/lib`

By using terminal

```
java -jar /Users/<your computer name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguardgui.jar
```

[proguardgui tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y91l9.png)

Now click on the retrace option on the left menu side to get the below window,  browse your `mapping.txt` file from the above location and add your stack trace error logs in the obfuscated stack trace window and then click on the `ReTrace` button to get the deObfuscated error report.

> There is one more way of doing automatically using Google play store
> console.
>
> [Check this website of Google Play Store Console for detailed
> steps.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en&visit_id=637715425045935177-2716002647&rd=1)

Comment: Oh my, this is incredible. All this time I've been doing it by hand T.T

Answer (score 1):

Another option (works for me).
Location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin (java.exe is here)

1. Add the files from Sdk\tools\proguard\lib:

   proguard.jar

   retrace.jar
2. Add your mapping.txt and stacktrace file
3. Create a bat file with the lines:

   java -jar retrace.jar -verbose mapping.txt stacktrace

   pause
4. Run it.