# intent redirection vulnerability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-security

I recently published a game in Play Console, but it is showing a warning of 'intent redirection vulnerability' and requesting me to cure it before due date. What do I have to do in terms of unity or android manifest file or c# programming to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're probably using Unity 2018+, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56274895

Otherwise it would be very helpful if you could share your Unity version, used packages and plugins. Probably it has nothing to do with your game at all.