# get warning "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection" but find no error in prelaunch

Tags: android, security, unity-game-engine, android-security, android-app-bundle

I just upload **App Bundle** that was exported using **Android Project** and **Unity3D**.

After upload I got an email that contains a warning:

> "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection."

However, checking at the pre-launch report on google play store, I found no error:

[image]

any idea?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175958/your-app-contains-an-intent-redirection-vulnerability

Comment: @PembaTamang i have read it, but i dont have Xiaomi SDK installed on my Unity

Comment: then I don't know whats wrong. Could be a false positive

Comment: See https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en