# How to Uninstall Xiaomi from Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console, xiaomi

I've been having issues with security while submitting to Google Play, but I've finally determined that the issue lies with Xiaomi Mi Game Center (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175958/your-app-contains-an-intent-redirection-vulnerability) and the first image, from my Play Console). However, I can't seem to find any way to uninstall it. The option to remove it has disappeared from my Build Settings (image 2), so I tried to find it via Finder and didn't have much luck. I searched for it, but I didn't want to just start deleting files willy nilly in case I deleted something important (image 3). Any idea how to get rid of it? I'm using Unity 2019.2.13f1 on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6. 
[image: Play Console Alerts]
[image: Build Settings Screen]
[image: Searching for Xiaomi in /Applications/Unity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove it from the Build Settings indeed, I do see the option to remove it, but I am on 2018.4.11f1.

[image: Remove via build settings]

Can you try going to the package manager via Window --> Package Manager, and checking there? I do see it there, with also an option to remove it.

[image: Remove via package manager]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Problem solved, and my app is live :D