# Google Play Console: Vulnerable Intent Redirection

Tags: android, publishing

While publishing an app got an email from Google Play Console `Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection`

This is the whole [email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwHyp.jpg) in this image

What to do please help me out?

Comment: Have the steps mentioned in the link in the email not worked?
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en

Comment: This may help you to identify the component which is causing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175958/your-app-contains-an-intent-redirection-vulnerability#:~:text=%22One%20or%20more%20of%20your%20apps%20contains%20an,Console%20alerts%20will%20be%20removed%20from%20Google%20Play.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't find the "Play Console/Alert tab" mentioned in the linked question - anyone know where it is in the new layout developer console?

Comment: Google helpfully removed the Alert tab with the new re-design of the Play Console so now you only get the bland email and no way to specifically identify the cause.

Comment: hi, last month we are also facing the same issue, i would like to know that your problem resolved or not, if you know how to rectify this issue please help me.