# How to fix Intent Redirection vulnerability?, and I am not using any Xiaomi dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-security

I've been having trouble fixing this issue for weeks now, and still no luck. My app is keep getting rejected from PlayStore. I read https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en
and I tried option-1 adding `exported=false` in every activity, but it didn't work. Then I tried option-2.

Activity 1

```
val intentProduct = Intent(context,ProductView::class.java)
    intentProduct.putExtra("data",gson.toJson(item))
    startActivity(intentProduct)
```

Activity 2

```
if (callingActivity != null && callingActivity!!.packageName == BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID){
    var product = gson.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("data"), Product::class.java)
    //other stuff
}
```

But when I try this I'm always getting NullPointerException because the callingActivity is always null, so because of that, it's going into the else condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, the issue was in one of the payment libraries I was using, RazorPay, I simply fixed it by updating the library to the latest version, Posted my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499225/13373099