# Flutter Razorp,Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android, flutter, android-security, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I have used the latest razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.4 dependency in the app.
when uploaded to place console i received mail from the team as

"
Intent Redirection
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article.

com.razorpay.x2.onReceive
"

I searched online the solution were to update razorpay implementaion

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175958/your-app-contains-an-intent-redirection-vulnerability) they suggested to change version razorpay android sdk version to the latest one.

how to do that in flutter

the pubdev package used is very recently updated

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version
razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.2

This solved the issue for me.