# Viewmodel with dagger-hilt didn't work after applied Proguard

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, proguard, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am working on app that uses MVVM, Room and dagger hilt, the app is crashed after applied Proguard rules, `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources`

the output

```
2021-08-11 08:30:56.952 13679-13679/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.dummyappv3, PID: 13679
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'e.f.a.i.a e.f.a.i.c.b' on a null object reference
        at com.test.dummyappv3.viewmodels.PostViewModel.<init>(Unknown Source:43)
        at e.f.a.g$k$a.get(:3)
        at d.p.a.c(:8)
        at d.p.a.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at f.a.a.c.b.d.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at d.p.w.a(:3)
        at com.test.dummyappv3.ui.home.HomeFragment.T(:3)
        at d.n.b.m.n0(Unknown Source:19)
        at d.n.b.h0.f(:4)
        at d.n.b.h0.k(:8)
        at d.n.b.b0.S(:1)
        at d.n.b.b0.w(:3)
        at d.n.b.h0.f(:8)
        at d.n.b.h0.k(:8)
        at d.n.b.b0.S(:1)
        at d.n.b.b0.w(:3)
        at d.n.b.p.onStart(:4)
        at d.b.c.k.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7923)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Obviously the error refers to the injected **repository constructor** in the viewmodel class, it's look the proguard converted it to this letters **`'e.f.a.i.a e.f.a.i.c.b'`**

**Viewmodel**

```
@HiltViewModel
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "PostViewModel";


    private Repository repository = null;
    public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> finalURL = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> token = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> label = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> ifAnythingWrongHappened = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Inject
    public PostViewModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;  //<<< Here
    }

    public final LiveData<List<Item>> getAllPostsFromDB
            = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(repository.localDataSource.getAlItems());


    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void getPosts() {
        ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(false);
        Log.e(TAG, finalURL.getValue());

        repository.remoteDataSource.getPostList(finalURL.getValue())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<PostList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull PostList postList) {
                        Log.e(TAG, postList.getNextPageToken());
                        token.setValue(postList.getNextPageToken());
                        postListMutableLiveData.setValue(postList);
                        for (int i = 0; i < postList.getItems().size(); i++) {
                            repository.localDataSource.insertItem(postList.getItems().get(i))
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                    .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete() {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: "+e.getMessage() );
                                            ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(true);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        finalURL.setValue(finalURL.getValue() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
                        ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
}
```

I searched for the **Viewmodel** and **Dagger-hilt** rules for the proguard, I added the viewmodels rules but I didn't find any modern ruels for dagger2 or dagger-hilt, however I found old rules for dagger1 and I added it with some edits

Here's the full proguard rules

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-dontpreverify

-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**


# Enable Optimization. # Optimization is turned off by default.
-optimizations   code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification


#Disable Optimization
#-dontoptimize
#-dontpreverify

# Remove Log command from code
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log{
 public static *** d(...);
 public static *** i(...);
 public static *** v(...);
}

# -------------------------------------------------
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep public class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-keep class androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {*;}
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider {*;}
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar {*;}
-keep class androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent {*;}
-keep class androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat {*;}

# -------------------------------------------------
-injars libs
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Signature, Exception, EnclosingMethod, InnerClasses
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface

# Keep source file name and line number
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep class okhttp3.** {*;}
-keep interface okhttp3.** {*;}
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keep interface okio.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.activeandroid.**

-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer

-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**

# Dontwarn-----------------------------------------
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.**


-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}


# -------------------------------------------------
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}


# Support Library
-keep class android.support.** {*;}
-keep interface android.support.** {*;}


# Needed when building against Marshmallow SDK.
  -dontwarn android.app.Notification


# Retrofit and GSON
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**

-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe.**

-keep public class com.google.gson.** {*;}
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**

#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {@retrofit2.http.* <methods>;}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * { @retrofit2.* <methods>;}
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor



# OkHttp and Picasso
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**



# Keep line number
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable


# Google Play Admob
    -keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
        public *;
    }

    -keep public class com.google.ads.** {
         public *;
    }

    -keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
    -dontwarn com.google.ads.** # Temporary workaround for v6.2.1. It gives a warning that you can ignore

    # Facebook
-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.facebook.**


-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Lru Cache
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.LruCache { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.LruCache.**

# Firebase
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.firebase.**

-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**

-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**

-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform

## Android architecture components: Lifecycle
# LifecycleObserver's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
# ViewModel's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
# keep Lifecycle State and Event enums values
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
# keep methods annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent even if they seem to be unused
# (Mostly for LiveData.LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChange(), but who knows)
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.arch.**

-keep class com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
-dontwarn com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView


#Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.HardwareConfigState

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-keep class org.ocpsoft.prettytime.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.ocpsoft.prettytime.**


#ViewModel

## Android architecture components: Lifecycle
# LifecycleObserver's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
# ViewModel's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
# keep Lifecycle State and Event enums values
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
# keep methods annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent even if they seem to be unused
# (Mostly for LiveData.LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChange(), but who knows)
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }

#all

-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }

#retRofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
# Orm
-keep class * extends com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.DatabaseHolder { *; }

# Fresco

-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**

# com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keepattributes *Annotation,Signature
-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.**
-keep class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.**{ *; }
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn uk.co.senab.photoview.**

#Image Cropper
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }



# Keep source file names, line numbers, and Parse class/method names for easier debugging
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
 -keepnames class com.parse.** { *; }


 # Required for Parse
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -keepattributes Signature
 -dontwarn com.squareup.**
 -dontwarn okio.**


-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keep @interface dagger.*,javax.inject.*
-keep @dagger.Module class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.inject.* *;
    @dagger.* *;
    ();
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  @javax.inject.* ;
}
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class **$$ModuleAdapter
-keep class **$$InjectAdapter
-keep class **$$StaticInjection

-keep class dagger.** { *; }
-keep class * extends dagger.** { *; }
-keep interface dagger.** {*;}
-dontwarn dagger.internal.codegen.**

-keep class * extends dagger.hilt.*
```

in build gradle

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56007176/6478047 . You will get a mapping file in build->outputs->mapping -> release -> mapping.txt . Use it to get proper stacktrace

Comment: @manohar According to my understanding this will deobfuscate my code only on google play to read it?

Comment: As far a I know this will only deobfuscate the crash reports .

Answer (score 0):

Please try after adding the following lines in your proguard's file.

```
-keepnames @dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
```

Hope this one works.

Reference : https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/hilt/android/lifecycle/proguard-rules.pro