# Android Proguard obscation issue for Azure Blob Storage Library

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, azure-blob-storage, proguard

I am implementing the Azure Storage blob library for uploading files to the server.
It is working well for debug build but giving issues for the signed build.

If I make `minifyEnabled false` in the main modules(app) build.gradle file then it works well.
Azure dependency is added in one of the modules (utils) of the projects

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
    R8$$SyntheticClass:19 -> Unhandled Exception
R8$$SyntheticClass:26 -> java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions: jackson-annotations=unknown, jackson-core=unknown, jackson-databind=unknown,
jackson-dataformat-xml=unknown, jackson-datatype-jsr310=unknown, azure-core=1.21.0
at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:24)
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:6)
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:1)
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:10)
at g3.g.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:1)
at g3.g.a(ModelHelper.java:1)
at d3.n.a(BlobUrlParts.java:16)
at le.a.<init>(AzureManager.kt:22)
at wc.s.c(LoggerManager.kt:51)
at wc.c.f(AuthenticationManager.kt:658)
at wc.c$a.j(Unknown Source:11)
at dh.a.d(ContinuationImpl.kt:8)
at sh.k0.run(DispatchedTask.kt:109)
at yh.f.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:12)
at zh.j.run(Tasks.kt:3)
at zh.a$b.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:85)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Method java.io.OutputStream l5.e.j(java.io.OutputStream, k4.b)
overrides final method in class Lh4/e; (declaration of 'l5.e' appears in /data/app/~~eabNHREnGf5V2l7IFfclDA==/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch-TL7eUAKIO8SLVyPKiAm16Q==/base.apk)
at l5.f.r(XmlMapper.java:1)
at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperFactory.java:1)
at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:3)
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:6) 
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:1) 
at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:10) 
at g3.g.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:1) 
at g3.g.a(ModelHelper.java:1) 
at d3.n.a(BlobUrlParts.java:16) 
at le.a.<init>(AzureManager.kt:22) 
at wc.s.c(LoggerManager.kt:51) 
at wc.c.f(AuthenticationManager.kt:658) 
at wc.c$a.j(Unknown Source:11) 
at dh.a.d(ContinuationImpl.kt:8) 
at sh.k0.run(DispatchedTask.kt:109) 
at yh.f.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:12) 
at zh.j.run(Tasks.kt:3) 
at zh.a$b.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:85)
```

Below it the snippet of Azure dependency in utils modules build.gradle

```
// Azure
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.14.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
```

Below isippetst the code snippett of app modules proguard-rule.pro rule files.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, EnclosingMethod, Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, *Annotation*
-keep class androidx.health.services.client.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.libraries.healthdata.** { *; }
-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
-keep class com.azure.core.**{*;}
```

Below is the code snippet of app modules consumer-rule.pro files.

```
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
-keep class com.azure.core.**{*;}
```

Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minimizing using proguard is always a try-and-error game. You need to identify the used libraries that can not be minimized and/or obfuscated. Based on the error message it is clear that you should try to add Jackson library classes also to the keep list.

Comment: ``-keep class com.bea.xml.**{*;}
-keep class com.fasterxml.**{*;}``

I updated proguard-rule.pro file..
I getting this error.
``R8$$SyntheticClass:19 -> Unhandled Exception
E  R8$$SyntheticClass:26 -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: v3.g
at v3.g.a(ModelHelper.java:1)
at s3.n.a(BlobUrlParts.java:16)
Caused by: eg.a: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
at eg.b.c(FactoryFinder.java:58)
at eg.b.b(FactoryFinder.java:310)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.<init>(XmlFactory.java:10)``

Comment: @Robert: Can you please elaborate more, what should I check in provided link.?

Comment: Sorry wrong link posted. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56006933/150978 for deobfuscating Stack Trace.

Comment: This is fixed. By keeping(keep) in proguard rule files, the classes which were giving issue(by checking logs).
Thanks all for help.