# How to R8 de-obfuscate a library you own?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, maven, maven-central

Introduction:
I have deployed an Android Library to Maven Central. I see Maven is providing this artefact correctly but, perfectly readable. I'm trying to obfuscate the code to avoid this behaviour as we don't want that behaviour, we want to keep our library closed-source by the moment.

Problem:
I have configured Gradle to obfuscate the library enabling the Minify and setting some Proguard rules for the data classes.
I guess if I deploy this library to Maven, will now be obfuscated thus unreadable, am I correct?
If the answer is yes, I will need to decode the error logs in case of a crash or debug. If the library is obfuscated will be impossible to read. I have the mapping.txt file, in a normal App this can be uploaded to Google Play with the bundle to decode the logs.
In this case I don't know how to do it. Does somebody know how to de-obfuscate the logs in an Android Library uploaded to Maven Central?

I haven't found much info online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56006933/869736

Comment: @LouisWasserman that question is for the Play Store. This is a stand alone Android library.